# Need to re-configure my git

Tags: git, github

I had a bad bug in my app, so I deleted it locally and pulled down the working version from my github.

However, now when I try to run git 'add .' I get the below error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

How can I configure this app to my existing git repo? So I can push code to it again, and deploy.

It's hooked up to my domain, and heroku so I don't want to create a new repo.

Comment: Ask another question for you new error.  Please accept and upvote the answer that solved your first question.  To your second question though, you should correctly configure the remote repository.  Please read sections 1 through 4 of [Pro Git on Git Documentation](http://git-scm.com/documentation)

Comment: Weird. Try deleting the local directory again and rerunning `git clone <GitHub URL>`. This time, be sure to cd into the newly cloned directory.

Comment: @RudyMatela - accept and upvote? does SO rules says you should upvote too after accepting?

Comment: @rmagnum2002 not really, just suggesting. :) take it easy.

Comment: be sure, I took it very easy :). It's what I do always with a good answer, accept it then upvoting it. The reason I've asked you this is that I saw people asking to accept answers (and that's a good thing), but never saw someone to ask for upvote yet. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.git directory is missing. In the local repo

```
git init
git remote add origin /path/to/your/remote/repo
git pull
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is that the directory is really missing, and not just that the OP forgot to cd into his newly cloned directory before running `git add .`?

Comment: before push invoke git push origin master, do some git status as well